# How to send a view to the background so that it's behind the main view?

Tags: ios, swift

**Objective**

I would like to hide a `AVCaptureSession` behind the main view so that it's hidden under the `UIViewController` because it's not visible to the user.

Apparently, `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` is a subclass of `CALayer` that we use to display video as it is being captured by an input device.

**Code**

This is the code I am using to begin a session. The code begins a `AVCaptureSession` and uses `previewLayer` to place its frame in a layer of the view.

```
var err : NSError? = nil
    captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &err))

    if err != nil {
        println("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
    }

    var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)


    self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    previewLayer?.frame = self.view.layer.frame
    captureSession.startRunning()
```

**Question**

Others have suggested using `view.sendSubviewToBack(cameraView)` but I don't know how to implement it in my code. How do I place the frame of the session behind the main view, so that it is hidden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mentioned `sendSubviewToBack` method only works for views, you have layer, therefore you need a different solution.

What you need is something along the lines of

```
self.view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, atIndex: 0)
```

That will insert the `previewLayer` as the first layer in the current layer hierarchy.

Or if you want the layer to be added behind the `self.view.layer` you need to get the parent / super layer of `self.view.layer` like `self.view.layer.superlayer` and add the subview there.

**Clarification regarding the index 0**
Index 0 will result in the layer beeing the first to be displayed / rendered. If you have a Layer at index 1 which spans among 3/4 of the screen, on the remaining 1/4 the layer at index 0 would be visible.
If you add a view or layer by the regular addSublayer / addSubview it will get inserted as the latest and last object in the view hierarchy, the one with the highest index, the one that will be rendered last.

Comment: Not really, index 0 means it is the first to get rendered, meaning it would be placed at the back, since everything else gets placed on top of it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification. Is there another way to completely hide the layer? It seems like `previewLayer` is being mixed up with the view of the `UIViewController`. I now see the objects of the main view (such as `UILabels, UIImages`) and the `previewLayer`, at the same time. Is there any way to get around this issue?

Comment: Edit regarding my previous comment*: yes, you actually mentioned `self.view.layer.superlayer `. May you please tell me how to get the parent super layer? Thank you. I do really appreciate your help!

Comment: You can just set its opacity to 0 or hidden to true, but i don´t know what effect that might have on the actual AVCapture. The question is why you want to add the layer to your view but not be able to see it.

Comment: Setting the `opacity` to 0 and adding the layer to the index 0 solved my issue. I can't thank you enough!